# Preventing similar PHP included files from executing at the same time

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following three files:

```
index.php
menu.php
move.js
```

In index.php I've got 2 similar figures that have the same header. I've included the header as a menu.php file. In the header, there's a button "ClickMe". What I intended to do is whenever the button is clicked another div should move to the right and the text changes to "Changed Text", then when the button is clicked again the div should move back to the center and the text changes to "Original Text". All that works well when I include menu.php into index.php once. But as soon as I add menu.php another time, the div moves to the right and runs back to the center when I cick on the button.

Is there a way to prevent the javascript listener from executing multiple times while still including the same file multiple times in index.php file?

Here is my code:

**index.php**

```
 //...................
        <figure class="front">
             <?php include ("menu.php"); ?>               
        </figure>
        <figure class="back">
             <?php include ("menu.php"); ?>
        </figure>
    //..........................
```

**menu.php**

```
//...........
<button id="mover" type="button" >ClickMe</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/move.js"></script>
```

**move.js**

```
//moves the figure to the right when clicked, and returns it to the center when clicked again
var collapsed = false;

$('#mover').on('click', function () {

    if (collapsed) {
        console.log("true");
        $("#container").animate({
            left: 0
        }, "slow", function () {

            $('#mover').html('Original text');
        });

        collapsed = false;

    } else {
        console.log("false");
        $("#container").animate({
            left: '25%'
        }, "slow", function () {

            $('#mover').html('Changed text');
        });

        collapsed = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: [`include_once()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) ?

Comment: If they don't want to include a file more than once they could easily not include it.  Is that really their issue?

Comment: If you used include more than just to try it... You would know that including a file may include some others. That is the use of `include_once()`.

Comment: Seems they want 'include_once' behaviour for the imported JS not the Php.

Comment: When I used include_once(), the thing worked but the issue is that I have two figures that are back to back to one another. So when I use include_once the button doesn't show when I flip the figure.

Comment: Don’t label the button with an “id” as an id should be unique. Make it a class “mover” then find a jquery way to only get the doc you want.

Comment: So you use PHP include to split out logical parts of your HTML... Okay. Think again. How you'll you write it if it was in the same file? Would it have the same `id` twice? Then why not call the `move.js` in index.php instead of having it called twice? There is some bear scratching for you in 2018.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that with including menu.php twice you create two HTML elements with the same ID "mover", which is invalid HMTL to begin with but also means the JS is included twice as well and will trigger on both of them at the same time.

You might want to restructure your application, separate the JS and include it only once and create buttons with different IDs for "front" and "back".

Answer (score 1):

There are likely JS workarounds to get similar behaviour to Php's 'include_once' for JS assets.

Here is a Php based approach to uniquely importing JS assets:

```
<?php

class JsImporter
{
    public $srcs = [];

    public function importOnce($src)
    {
        if(!in_array($src, $this->srcs))
            $this->srcs[] = $src;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        $o = "\n";
        foreach($this->srcs as $src)
            $o.= '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . $src . '"></script>';

        return $o . "\n";
    }
}

$jsImporter = new JsImporter;

?>
<html>
<body>

    <!-- this code in include -->
    <button>Click Me</button>
    <?php $jsImporter->importOnce('thing.js'); ?>

    <!-- this code in include -->
    <button>Click Me</button>
    <?php $jsImporter->importOnce('thing.js'); ?>

    <?= $jsImporter; // output script elements at footer. ?>

</body>
</html>
```

This will insert one script element at the foot of the html body.

(If you are repeating blocks of html, ensure you don't repeat element ids.)